# how to set a password for a specified database in MySQL

Tags: java, php, mysql, database

how to set a password for a specified database of databases that exists in MySQL?

I want to prevent users to not to see the structure of my tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can grant privileges to the users only for a specific database.
For example, the following code grants the right to execute SELECT to "the_user" on "your_database".

```
GRANT Select ON your_database.* TO the_user@%;
```

If your user has privileges to all your databases, it maybe convenient to revoke all the privileges before granting. In this case use the following syntax

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM the_user@%;
```

Hope this will helps